# Trig functions of inverse trig functions identities.

Tags: trigonometry

I found these identities online.

$$\cos(\arcsin(\omega)) = \sqrt{1-\omega^2}$$

$$\sin(\arccos(\omega)) = \sqrt{1-\omega^2}$$

$$\cos(\arctan(\omega)) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}$$

$$\sin(\arctan(\omega)) = \frac{\omega}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}$$

$$\tan(\arccos(\omega)) = \frac {\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}{\omega}$$

$$\tan(\arcsin(\omega)) = \frac{\omega} {\sqrt{1 - \omega^2}}$$

I'm wondering how can these be found or proved

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Sebastiano I didn't really try anything, since I have so little to work with here

Comment: Draw the triangles for them and you'll see it.

Comment: Just do them.  $\arcsin \omega$ is by definition the angle $\theta: -\frac \pi 2\le \theta \le \frac \pi 2$ so that $\sin theta = \omega$.  As $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ we have $\cos \theta = \pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}$.  As $ -\frac \pi 2\le \theta \le \frac \pi 2$ we no $\cos \theta \ge 0$ so $\cos \theta =\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$.  ANd as $\theta = \arcsin \omega$ we have $\cos(\arcsin\omega)=\cos(\theta) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin \omega)} = \sqrt{1 -\omega^2}$.  They all follow the same way.  Just do them.

Answer (score 4):

**Remember**: when you take the arcsine, arccosine, and arctangent of a number, the output is an **angle**.

For the first one, for example, draw yourself a right triangle with an angle $\theta = \arcsin(\omega)$; i.e. a triangle with an angle $\theta$ whose sine is $\omega$—simply choose lengths for the opposite side and the hypotenuse so that the ratio of these two comes out to be $\omega$ (label these side lengths on your picture). No need to worry that there are many such triangles: one can prove that all right triangles with that ratio of lengths between a leg and the hypotenuse are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles) (therefore the ratios between any two sides—in particular, the sine, cosine, and tangent of $\theta$—of any such triangle will be the same).

Once you've drawn such a triangle, use the Pythagorean theorem$^\dagger$ if necessary to deduce the length of the missing side, and then, looking at your picture, simply take the cosine of that angle (divide the length of the side adjacent to $\theta$ by the length of the hypotenuse).

---

$^\dagger$Indeed, the Pythagorean theorem is the source of the $\sqrt{1 \pm \omega^2}$ in all of these identities, since using it to find the missing side involves solving for one of the letters in $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ (where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are side lengths of a right triangle).

Answer (score 3):

For example we know that if an inverse function exists it is unique.

$$\cos(\omega)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\omega)}$$

Putting $\omega \to \arcsin(\omega)$ we have the plus sign (definition of inverse function that you should remember)

$$\cos(\arcsin(\omega))=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(\omega))}=\sqrt{1-\omega^2}$$

Hence being $\sin(\omega)= \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\omega)}$

$$\sin(\arccos(\omega))= \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos(\omega))}=\sqrt{1-\omega^2}$$

and after I suggest also this video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3eIhBlLx0Y&ab_channel=IntegralsForYou for the other identities.

Comment: Wow that's nice, thank you so much :)